# Associativity of symmetric difference (set theory): $(A\Delta B) \Delta C = A \Delta (B\Delta C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a proof of why $(A\Delta B) \Delta C = A \Delta (B\Delta C)$, where
$A\Delta B = (A\cup B) \setminus (B\cap A)$.

A bit into the proof is where I stop understanding, here:

$(A\cup B \cup C) \cap (A\cup B^c \cup C^c) \cap (A^c\cup B \cup C^c) \cap(A^c \cup B^c \cup C)$ =

$(B \cup C \cup A) \cap (B \cup C^c \cup A^c) \cap (B^c \cup C^c \cup A^c) \cap (B^c \cup C^c \cup A)$

What kind of rules are used in that equality?

Comment: Commutativity and associativity of union and intersection?

Comment: [Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Comment: @samjoe and Mauro, if you look closely, there is a general rearrangement of terms *except* for the last one $(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)$, which becomes $(B^c\cup C^c\cup A^c)$ (the second-to-last). Unless there is a typo in the question.

Comment: No typo @G.Sassatelli

Comment: @Mathaniel Then, correct it, please.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli there was a typo in my comment, not in my post lol (the comment typo has been corrected)

Comment: @Mathaniel Ah, you meant that the version in the OP is what it should be. Ok.

Comment: Yeah, it's correct @samjoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a typo. The penultimate factor should probably be $B^c \cup C\cup A^c$. Then what's in work here is only the commutative law of unions and intersections.

You can always check the validity of each step using truth tables.

---

Another solution is to see that symmetric difference is basically the same as addition modulo $2$ of the characteristic function. That is that we count the number of sets an element is in and if that's odd it's part of the symmetric difference. It alls boils down to the fact that addition is associative.

Comment: The elements that are in exactly one of $A$ or $B$ or $C$, right? But I don't understand how that helps me at that point in the proof.

Comment: I don't know how I'm supposed to begin to write that in mathematical symbols: If $x \in A\Delta B \to x\in A$ or $x\in B$ (but not $x\in A$ AND $x\in B$). So if $x\in A \Delta (B \Delta C)$, 1) $x \in A$ or 2) $x\in B$ or $x \in C$ Similar argumentation for $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$. Something like that?

Comment: @Mathaniel But agreed, it's not a continuation of your approach. Frankly speaking I don't see how you come to that expression.

Comment: I found it on the net: http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Exploration_and_Proof/divided_difference.pdf

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found too. It should be $(A\cup B \cup C) \cap (A\cup B^c \cup C^c) \cap (A^c\cup B \cup C^c) \cap (A^c\cup B^c \cup C) = (B\cup C \cup A) \cap (B^c\cup C^c\cup A^c) \cap (B^c\cup C \cup A^c) \cap (B^c\cup C^c \cup A)$ which is correct :)

Comment: No, there should be no factor with only complements. There's one factor where all three sets are non-complemented and three where all but one is complemented. That makes it possible to commute them so the expressions becomes the same.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a typo. My bad. Thank you so much though! You're basically just rearranging the letters (A takes the place of C B takes the place of A and C takes the place of B, but the complements stay in teh same place)